# How to find occurrence while patterns are overlapping

Tags: java, regex

**Context:**
It is a log analysis thing. I am creating a `regex` program to find occurrence of certain requests send to a server from a client. I have the client log file containing these requests along with other logs.

**Problem:**
When a request message is send to server, the client should have 2 log statements like:

```
sending..
message_type
```

when the above statements or pattern found we can say one request has been sent.It is combined pattern. Ok

We are expecting the log file content will be like

```
sending..
message_type
...//other text
sending..
message_type
...//other text
sending..
message_type
```

From the above log we can say client has sent 3 messages. But in the actual log file somehow, the patterns are overlapping as below(not for all messages, but for some):

```
sending..(1)
...//other text
sending..(2)
message_type(2)
...//other text
message_type(1)
sending..(3)
message_type(3)
```

Still 3 requests(i numbered messages to understand). But the pattern is overlapped.i.e before logging first message fully , second message got logged.
The above explanation is for understanding. Below is the part of original log:

**Original log**

```
Send message to server:
Created post notification log dir
Created post notification log dir
Created post notification log dir
Send message to server:
Created post notification log dir
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><request xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="createsession"/></message>
INFO [a] - Server Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><response xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="ok"></params></response></message>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><request xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="createsession"/></message>
INFO [a] - Server Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><response xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="ok"></response></message>
```

here as per the explanation single request will be identified with its 2 parts:

```
Send message to server:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><request xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="createsession"/></message>
```

**What I tried**

```
public class LogMatcher {   

    static final String create_session= "Send message to server(.){10,1000}(<\\?xml(.){10,500}type=\"createsession\"(.){1,100}</message>)";



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("D:/dummy.txt"))));//I put the above log in this file
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null ){     
            b.append(line);
        }

        findMatch(b,"Send message to server","Send message to server");
        findMatch(b,create_session,"create_session");

    }
    private static int findMatch(StringBuilder b,String pattern, String type) {
        int count =0;
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(b.toString());
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            count++;
        } 
        System.out.printf("%25s%2d\n",type+": ",count);
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Current Output**

Intention is to find out the number of `createsession` messages sent

```
Send message to server:  2
        create_session:  1
```

**Expected output**

From the log it is clear that 2 messages sent.So out put will be:

```
 Send message to server:  2
         create_session:  2
```

You can see the pattern I have tried in my code. Can anyone suggest a pattern to get the desired result?

*Note: One can simply say why not use the count `Send message to server` alone. Because in the log there are many type of messages like `login, closesession` etc. All of them having the first part as `Send message to server`.Also they have logged message types alone for some other purpose so we can't relay on any part(meaning only the combination we could relay on)*

Comment: So why don't you count `type=\"createsession\"` alone? ... And what prevents it from logging `sending (1)` + `sending (2)` + `message (1)` + `message (2)`?

Comment: Why because, these `type=\"createsession\"` xmls are logged along with `Send message to server` as well as some other ways like stored in `db`. So we can't simply rely on that.

Comment: So how would you know if there's a "*other way*" of `type=\"createsession\"` in between `Send message to server` and the xml you want to match? Could you show an example of a xml you'd want to ignore?

Comment: "other way" that you can neglect here , that will have like `Store in DB :` instead of `Send message to server` and the xml message. I just want to know how we can tackle this overlapping situation

Answer (score 1):

> Find occurrence of certain requests send to a server from a client.
>
> > "other way" that you can neglect here , that will have like `Store in DB :` instead of `Send message to server` and the xml message.

I'd propose a new strategy:

1. Use only 1 regex to match all alternatives, to parse the the log only once (improving performance in long files).
2. Match *`type=\"createsession\"`* xmls independently.
3. Also match *`Store in DB:`* xmls, but ignore them (don't increment the counter).

We can use the following expression to match the number of messages sent to server.

```
^(?<toserver>Send message to server:)
```

- Notice I'm using a [named group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), we can later reference as `regexMatcher.group("toserver")` to increment the counter.

And match the target xmls independently as:

```
^(?<message><\? *xml\b.{10,500} type *= *\"createsession\")
```

- Later referenced as `regexMatcher.group("message")`.
- We'll use an independent counter.

So, how do we ignore *`Store in DB:`* xmls? We can match them, while not creating a capture.

```
^Store in DB ?:\r?\n(?:.*\n)*?<\? *xml\b.*
```

- It matches the literal `Store in DB :`, followed by
- `\r?\n(?:.*\n)*?` as few lines as possible, until
- `<\? *xml\b.*` it matches the fist `<?xml` line

---

**Regex**

```
^(?:Store in DB ?:\r?\n(?:.*\n)*?<\? *xml\b.*|(?<toserver>Send message to server:)|(?<message><\? *xml\b.{10,500} type *= *\"createsession\"))
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ0bM7/1)</kbd>

---

**Code**

```
static final String create_session = "^(?:Store in DB ?:\\r?\\n(?:.*\\n)*?<\\? *xml\\b.*|(?<toserver>Send message to server:)|(?<message><\\? *xml\\b.{10,500} type *= *\\\"createsession\\\"))";

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    //for testing purposes
    final String text = "Send message to server:\nCreated post notification log dir\nCreated post notification log dir\nCreated post notification log dir\nSend message to server:\nCreated post notification log dir\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><message schema_version=\"3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e\"><request xaction_guid=\"new xaction guid\" type=\"createsession\"/></message>\nStore in DB :\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><message schema_version=\"3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e\"><request xaction_guid=\"new xaction guid\" type=\"createsession\"/></message>\nINFO [a] - Server Response: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><message schema_version=\"3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e\"><response xaction_guid=\"new xaction guid\" type=\"ok\"></params></response></message>\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><message schema_version=\"3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e\"><request xaction_guid=\"new xaction guid\" type=\"createsession\"/></message>\nINFO [a] - Server Response: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><message schema_version=\"3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e\"><response xaction_guid=\"new xaction guid\" type=\"ok\"></response></message>";
    System.out.println("INPUT:\n" + text + "\n\nCOUNT:");
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append(text);

    findMatch(b,create_session,"create_session");
}

private static int findMatch(StringBuilder b,String pattern, String type) {
    int count =0;  // counter for "Send message to server:"
    int countType=0; // counter for "type=\"createsession\""
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(b.toString());
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        if (regexMatcher.group("toserver") != null) {
            count++;
        } else if (regexMatcher.group("message") != null) {
            countType++;
        } else {
            // Ignoring "Store in DB :\n<?xml...."
        }
    } 
    System.out.printf("%25s%2d\n%25s%2d\n", "to server: ", count, type+": ", countType);
    return countType;
}
```

**Output**

```
INPUT:
Send message to server:
Created post notification log dir
Created post notification log dir
Created post notification log dir
Send message to server:
Created post notification log dir
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><request xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="createsession"/></message>
Store in DB :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><request xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="createsession"/></message>
INFO [a] - Server Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><response xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="ok"></params></response></message>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><request xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="createsession"/></message>
INFO [a] - Server Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><message schema_version="3644767c-2632-411a-9416-44f8a7dee08e"><response xaction_guid="new xaction guid" type="ok"></response></message>

COUNT:
              to server:  2
         create_session:  2
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/5pqgh1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Mariano, I like your named group and the strategy. I think I could start with this approach